# SDL2 RenderCopy multiple textures vs single Surface

Tags: c++, performance, sdl-2

Pretty self-explanatory.
Currently I copy portions of textures directly using RenderCopy
My idea is to blit these portions of data into a single surface instead and then make a texture out of it to RenderCopy after
What is faster?

Answer (score 1):

In most cases, it's probably faster to `RenderCopy()` each texture individually. I say this because SDL handles textures in the GPU, so it's already collecting data to a single surface behind the scenes, but in hardware, which is bounds faster.